# Для каких целей можно/нужно использовать Handlebars.js в форме авторизации/отправки сообщения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handlebars

Для каких целей можно/нужно использовать Handlebars.js в форме авторизации/отправки сообщения?